# Passing an integer array from one fragment to another

Tags: android

I am an amateur in Android app development.
I tried searching a lot but couldn't get a satisfactory answer.

Can anybody please tell me how I should go about doing this?

This is my Main Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
TopSection.TopSectionListener{
static int arr[];
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void sorting(int[] random) {
    arr=random;
    BottomSection bottomSection=(BottomSection) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment4);
    bottomSection.setArray(arr);
}
}
```

This is the code for my first fragment

```
    public class TopSection extends Fragment {
private static TextView top;
private static Button gen;
private static Button sort;
static int random[];
String s;

TopSectionListener activityCommander;

public interface TopSectionListener{
    public void sorting(int random[]);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        activityCommander=(TopSectionListener)context;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, container, false);
    top=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.top);
    gen=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.gen);
    sort=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sort);
    random=new int[20];
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        random[i]=0;
    }
    s="";
    top.setText(s);
    gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            butClk(v,s);
        }
    });
    sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickBut(v);
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void butClk(View view,String s){
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        random[i] = rand.nextInt(89) + 10;
        s+=random[i]+" ";
    }
    top.setText(s);
}

public void clickBut(View view){
    activityCommander.sorting(random);
}
}
```

And this is the code for my second fragment

```
    public class BottomSection extends Fragment {

int arr[];
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_section_fragment, container, false);
    populateQuickListView(view);
    populateMergeListView(view);
    return view;
}
public void setArray(int arr1[]){
    arr=arr1;
}
private void populateQuickListView(View view) {
    String a[]=new String[20];
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        a[i]=""+arr[i];
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.item_pop,a);
    ListView list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.quick);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void populateMergeListView(View view) {
    String a[]=new String[20];
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
       a[i]=""+arr[i];
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.item_pop,a);
    ListView list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.merge);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

I know it's a poorly written code, but I just begun and this thing has taken so much of my time.
Kindly help.

Comment: post your code we will help you better

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using interfaces. Here is a complete answer with example, just change to `int[]` from `String` .

[How to Pass text in tab1 to listview in tab2 tabbed activity android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060314/how-to-pass-text-in-tab1-to-listview-in-tab2-tabbed-activity-android/46061349#46061349)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass integer array from fragment to fragment. But you can pass integer array list. Convert your integer array to Arraylist and pass this as follows in first fragment

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.yourContainer,SecondFragment.newInstance(integerArray)).commit();
```

Add these codes in your second fragment in order to get the array

```
public static SecondFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Integer> intValues) {
    SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putIntegerArrayList(ARG_PARAM1, intValues);

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intValue = getArguments().getIntegerArrayList(ARG_PARAM1);

    }
}
```

Comment: the
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
is showing some problem. :(
Says it cannot resolve BlankFragment

Comment: These code must be added into your BottomSection fragment.did u add it?

Comment: Got it! done. Used services and broadcastreceiver. :)